# Computation of Troullier-Martins pseudowavefunctions

Tags: algorithms, computational-physics, nonlinear-equations

The computation of Troullier-Martins pseudo-wavefunctions has been
described in [1].
The pseudo-wavefunction $R^{\textrm{PP}}_l$ is defined by
$$
R^{\textrm{PP}}_l(r) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
R^{\textrm{AE}}_l(r)  & r \geq r_{\textrm{cl}} \\
f_l(r)  & r \leq r_{\textrm{cl}}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Here
$$
f_l(r) = r^l \exp(p(r))
$$

$$
p(r) = c_0 + c_2 r^2 + c_3 r^3 + c_4 r^4 .
$$
where $c_i$ are unknown coefficients ($c_1=0$).

The functions $R^{\textrm{AE}}_l$ are known and
the coefficients $c_i$ are defined by:
$$\int_0^{r_{\textrm{cl}}} \vert f_l(r) \vert^2 r^2 dr =
\int_0^{r_{\textrm{cl}}} \vert R^{\textrm{AE}}_l(r) \vert^2 r^2 dr
$$
$$
f_l(r_{\textrm{cl}}) = R^{\textrm{AE}}_l(r_{\textrm{cl}})
$$
$$
f'_l(r_{\textrm{cl}}) = (R^{\textrm{AE}})'_l(r_{\textrm{cl}})
$$
$$
f''_l(r_{\textrm{cl}}) = (R^{\textrm{AE}})''_l(r_{\textrm{cl}})
$$
How are these equations solved? What algorithm should be used?

#### References:

1. Troullier, N.; Martins, J. L. Efficient pseudopotentials for plane-wave calculations. *Phys. Rev. B* **1991,** *43* (3), 1993–2006. [DOI: 10.1103/PhysRevB.43.1993](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.43.1993).

Comment: I don't know this method, but at first glance I would rather express the polynomial in powers of $(r-r_{cl})$ instead of $r$, as this seems to simplify the matching equations. For which application do you need pseudopotentials, and of what?

Comment: It's a system of nonlinear equations that can't be solved by analytical solutions mostly because of that first equation in terms of integral. You need to solve it by using Newton-Raphson probably...

Comment: I use the pseudopotentials to compute atoms and small molecules in a three-dimensional basis set. The HGH potential for oxygen atom handles 2s (and 2p) electrons as valence electrons. As the 2s wavefunctions behave irregularly near the origin I thought that I should use the Troullier-Martins pseudopotentials instead of HGH.